Error in implementing LIME for Text data using scispacy en_core_m.... models
ValueError: [E1041] Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but got: <class 'list'>
Please help
I want to build the explainable part for text data using LIME. I am getting the above error when i run the following code
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer

# Load your spaCy model
nlp = scispacy_medical


input_text = "Your large input text here..."

# Create a spaCy compatible tokenizer function for lime
def spacy_tokenizer(text):
    return [token.text for token in nlp(text)]

# Create a LIME explainer
explainer = LimeTextExplainer(class_names=["class_1", "class_2"])

# Explain the model's predictions on the input text
exp = explainer.explain_instance(input_text, spacy_tokenizer, num_features=10)

# Visualize the explanation
exp.show_in_notebook(text=True)```

